# Keep kendo detail grid expanded after databind

Tags: javascript, data-binding, kendo-ui, grid

This is my current grid and detailExpand/Databind. You will see I tried to get the uid and then expand that row after a databind has been triggered. expandedRowUid console logs undefined. Can someone please help me get either correctly get the uid or provide an alternative solution so that once a databind is triggered the detail grid does not collapse or is expanded again after the databind.

```
   function teacherHierarchyGrid() {
       $("#teacherGrid").kendoGrid({
           detailInit: detailInit,
           selectable: true,
           dataBound: function () {
             console.log("Bind occured")
             this.expandRow($('tr[data-uid=' + expandedRowUid + ']'));
           },
          detailExpand: function (e)
             expandedRowUid = e.masterRow.data('uid');
             console.log(expandedRowUid)
         },
     })
  }
```

**Edit ** New Code still not working

```
    var expandedRow;
    function teacherHierarchyGrid() {
        $("#teacherGrid").kendoGrid({
            detailInit: detailInit,
            selectable: true,
            autoBind: false,
            dataBound: function(e){
                 if (expandedRow) {
                     console.log(expandedRow);
                     e.sender.expandRow($('tr[data-uid=' + expandedRow + ']'));
            }
          },
            detailExpand: function (e) {
                 expandedRow = e.sender.dataItem(e.masterRow).uid;
          },
      })
   }
```

Comment: Do you wish to expand all detail rows automatically? If so, [check this link](http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-auto-expand-all-detail-rows-in-a-kendo-grid-#Y7UlVX19GE2_ZUsfXFr8kg)

Answer (score 1):

First it might log undefined due the lack of {} in the detailExpand function:

```
detailExpand: function (e) {
             expandedRowUid = e.masterRow.data('uid');
             console.log(expandedRowUid);
             }
```

Second in the dataBound function you are missing a semicolon after `console.log("Bind occured")`

Third probably the uid associated to the row isn't the same after you recreate the rows: after the databound the same row might have a different uid since is generated by the widget. Try to refer the row to expand throught is dataItem Id.

Comment: Still not expanding the row. I did notice that the dataBind event was being fired twice so I made sure to make autoBind false. Posted my current code above

Comment: I apologize for my mistake: the third point wasn't true,via this keyword you actually select the grid widget. The problem is that the uid isn't probably the same after you recreate the rows: after the databound the same row might have a different uid. Try to refer the row to expand throught is dataItem Id. If you provide the code were you define the datasource i can help you further.